# Major defects of C

Tags: c, language-design

What are the major defects of the C Language? How should one answer this question in an interview? I mean what does C Lack now compared to newer languages?

Comment: Well it's 23 characters less than Z.  That's a defect I suppose.

Comment: While this question is very subjective, pretty much everyone agrees that the C declarator syntax is just awful.

Comment: Fascinating. A question *explicitly* about C has the C++ tag. *Why*, dare I ask?

Answer (score 9):

C is probably the most important single language ever invented.

C really accomplished all of its immediate goals and then far more. It really doesn't have "defects", *per se*, but rather *choices*, which defined it as an ideal system implementation language and as an acceptable although not perfect application language.

When C burst on the scene in the early 1970's, it was competing with Fortran, Basic, Cobol, and, particularly, assembly.  It ate all their respective lunches, as they say, and buried them as implementation languages. Fortran alone has survived although there are few programs that can be expressed in Fortran but not C.

To this day C is occasionally #1 on [the Tiobe index](http://www.tiobe.com/index.php/content/paperinfo/tpci/index.html), trading off first for second only to the much more specialized and also-insanely-popular Java.

Sure, C may not compare to Ruby, Lisp, or Python for dynamic and symbolic applications, but they didn't exist back then and aren't useful for implementations.  And all three are typically implemented in C, in a sort of "last laugh". Ruby is 200,000 lines of C, internally.

So yes, it didn't implement every possible programming paradigm. And to answer your specific question:

1. C is not reflective
2. C does not have garbage collection
3. C does not directly implement closures
4. Static typing: C is the ultimate "compile-time" language processor.
5. C is not directly object-oriented, and object-like packages in C tend to be clunky and no one uses them.
6. C is not type-safe. (But can be used in a type-safe style.)
7. C is not memory-safe. (No guarantees, but sometimes can be used a mostly-safe way.)
8. There are too many operator priorities.
9. Some of the operator priorities don't seem to have the most useful precedence.
10. C is purely imperative.

In the big picture, C is a structured high-level language in which anything *can* be built, but which doesn't have reflective and object-oriented properties that tend to allow larger and more sophisticated programs and abstractions. A genius writing C can do anything but most of us should use higher level languages when our problem domain allows it.

Comment: Type safety isn't modern practice?

Comment: C is a lot more type-safe than many people give it credit for.  The key issues are that (despite the spelling) it's not the `typedef` keyword that introduces a new type, its `struct`; and that compilers have historically performed silent implicit conversions between built-in types that aren't required by C.  Varargs functions are really the only place that you get type-nonsafety without explicitly requesting it.

Comment: C was designed to take over assembly. But its really great and many softwares are written into it including linux, unix, most windows and lots of lots of application and system. IF there are defects then there are work around thats why its so successful

Comment: 2. Manual memory management is advantage.
5. OO-programming not needed.
So you are not right there.

Comment: @GMan, very funny. Being \*-safe *is* modern practice; not so much; another story.

Comment: @Digital: Sorry, I read that wrong. But then I'll just jump on @caf's boat and say, while it's not as type-safe as it could be, it's not *totally* absent. @SJ: OO is a very useful modelling tool.

Comment: @S.J.., hmm, good point, maybe.  I rather like G/C and OO, I guess you don't. I'm afraid you are a bit out of step, but in the end we may have a well-understand application division between them all...

Comment: It's not OO. Why is that defect. Its not declarative/functional/parallel either. But few languages are all if any of these.

Comment: @DigitalRoss: It's a great stretch to state that not having all the features currently in vogue is a defect.

Comment: I would say you gave the 7 advantages of C...

Comment: Well, I redefined *"defects"* to *"choices"* and then enumerated those choices, so by then I wasn't .. precisely .. calling them *defects* any more. :-)

Comment: Thanks for all the good comments. Obviously, every commenter added some useful perspective and some great analysis. BTW, I forgot to mention that the dereference operator probably should have been postfix instead of prefix. DMR himself wrote about this once. (Among other things, it would have eliminated the need for `->`.)

Answer (score 2):

I don't consider C defective. It's a powerful language that has been used to write tons of successful software.

Compared to newer technologies, C requires more work and requires more skill. Also, newer languages have powerful new features. For reasons like these, C isn't used much any more. But that hardly makes it defective.

Answer (score 2):

Don't get me wrong, I love C, but not having namespaces is a real pain. Look at any code that makes heavy use of a C library and try and tell me differently.

Comment: In fairness, that wasn't as much as a problem in the 1970s and 1980s when C was under development.  Programs were a lot smaller with fewer identifiers to clash.

Comment: @dan04 you're absolutely correct. But libraries like GLib and OpenGL in C make my head spin because of the naming. They should've fixed it in C99.

Comment: This is perhaps the only real defect anyone has cited, but then again I'm not sure how formal namespace support buys you anything versus `mylib_` prefixes unless you want to count saving you typing (and even then, the preprocessor can do that for you..).

Answer (score 0):

uhh..not sure what you mean by defective, but at the core it's definitely not focused on OO programming and there is more work to keeping resources under control.

Comment: Since when is OO programming a requirement? Scheme/LISP/Haskell etc. don't support OO, yet are still reasonable languages...

Comment: i dont consider it a defect or a requirement (that's why i asked what he means by that)  but I do think that oo programming can be more useful in solving some problems. from that perspective one could possibly interpret that as a deficiency when compared to non-oo languages